# Inserção elementos em uma lista dinâmica

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

Fiz essa função, só que não sei se está certa, não dá erro na compilação, porém dá um erro quando aparece o `prompt` de que o programa parou de funcionar.

Inserção no inicio:

```
int inserir_no_inicio_da_lista (Lista* li, struct aluno al){
  if (li == NULL){
      return 0;
  }

  Elem* no;

  no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));

  if (no == NULL){
      return 0;
  }

  no -> dadosAlunos = al;
  no -> prox = (*li);

  *li = no;

  return 1;
}
```

Estruturas:

```
struct aluno {
  int matricula;
  char nome[30];
  float n1, n2, n3;
};
typedef struct elemento* Lista;

//Arquivo ListaDinEncad.c
struct elemento {
  struct aluno dadosAlunos;
  struct elemento *prox;
};
typedef struct elemento Elem;

Lista* criar_lista();
```

Cria Lista:

```
Lista* criar_lista() {
  Lista* li;
  li = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));

  if (li != NULL){
      *li = NULL;
  }
  return li;
}
```

Comment: qUAL O ERRO QUE DÁ ?

Comment: E falta também as `struct`s e `typedef`s para que todo mundo consiga perceber como estão definidas e entender os tipos que vem na função.

Comment: Tudo bem, já editei para melhor entendimento.

Comment: O código parece me estar a funcionar. Veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/I2LI8G). Como está a função `criar_lista` ? E como está o `main` ?

Comment: O main está igual o que está ai no link, a função criar_lista eu acabei de adicionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema aqui está relacionado com a sua pergunta anterior, e respetivo `Lista` versus `Lista*`. O `Lista` pelo `typedef` já é um ponteiro logo o `criar_lista` deve devolver apenas `Lista` e não `Lista*`, senão estaria a devolver um ponteiro para um ponteiro.

Para além disso a lógica está um pouco inconsistente. Se o objetivo era ficar com `NULL` como inicio, que é o que normalmente faz mais sentido, então bastaria apenas retornar `NULL`:

```
Lista* criar_lista() {
    return NULL;
}
```

Ou atribuir `NULL` no main diretamente que era melhor.

```
int main(){
    Lista listaDeAlunos = NULL;
}
```

Se o objetivo fosse criar um nó teria que fazer assim:

```
Lista criar_lista() {
    //Lista e não Lista* | sizeof(Elem) e não sizeof(Lista)

    Lista li = (Lista) malloc(sizeof(Elem)); 

    return li;
}
```

Repare que é `sizeof(Elem)` porque queremos alocar espaço para um nó. Se for `sizeof(Lista)` estamos a alocar espaço para um ponteiro que não é o que se pretende.

Mas isto cria-lhe lhe outros problemas, pois acaba criando um nó vazio e sem dados e que irá mostrar o lixo que apanha na memoria.

Por isso a minha sugestão é que afete diretamente no `main` o ponteiro inicial da lista a `NULL`

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone com `NULL` no `main`](https://ideone.com/I2LI8G)

Answer (score 0):

Segue o teu código com algumas alterações:

- criei uma struct para a lista, tendo um ponteiro para o primeiro Elem da lista
- modifiquei um trecho da tua inserção pois ele fazia apontamentos errados
- criei um método para mostrar a lista

struct da lista:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct aluno {
  int matricula;
  char nome[30];
  float n1, n2, n3;
} Aluno;

typedef struct elemento {
  struct aluno dadosAlunos;
  struct elemento *prox;
} Elem;

typedef struct lista {
    Elem *primeiro;
} Lista;

void criar_lista(Lista *list) {
    list->primeiro = NULL;
}

int inserir_no_inicio_da_lista (Lista* li, Aluno al){
  if (li == NULL){
      return 0;
  }
  Elem* no;

  no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
  if (no == NULL){
      return 0;
  }
  no -> dadosAlunos = al;
  no -> prox = li->primeiro;
  li->primeiro = no;
  return 1;
}

void mostra_lista(Lista list) {
    Elem *aux = list.primeiro;

    while (aux != NULL) {
        printf("\n %d - %s", aux->dadosAlunos.matricula, aux->dadosAlunos.nome);
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
}

int main() {
    Lista list; 
    Aluno a;

    criar_lista(&list);
    a.matricula = 1;
    strcpy(a.nome, "Jorge");
    a.n1 = 10;
    a.n2 = 8;
    a.n3 = 9;
    inserir_no_inicio_da_lista(&list, a);
    mostra_lista(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Chegou a testar? Deu certo pra ti?